# Why does using uchar matrix in opencv give me error results?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use opencv(4.2 c++) to get matrix's each value by pointer, because I need to process gray image by 8UC1.

When I use float matrix that was fine, but use uchar cannot work.

```
            cv::Mat src_f = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_32FC1);
            float* test_f = src_f.ptr<float>(0);
            cout << "test_f ptr address:" << test_f <<endl; 
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                cout << "test_f ptr value:" << *(test_f+i) <<endl; 
            }

            cv::Mat src_u = Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_8UC1);
            uchar* test_u = src_u.ptr<uchar>(0);
            cout << "test_u ptr address:" << test_u <<endl; 
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                cout << "test_u ptr value:" << *(test_u+i) <<endl; 
            }
```

and I got output like

```
test_f ptr address:0x562c91769280
test_f ptr value:1
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:1
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:1
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:0
test_f ptr value:1

test_u ptr address:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
test_u ptr value:
```

I can't get address or values. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to print numerical reperesentation of character on console you have to promote it to wider type for example `unsigned short`. Otherwise, you will see just character endoded by numeric value stored on `char` type.

```
cout << "test_u ptr value:" << (unsigned short)*(test_u+i) <<endl;
```

---

`operator<<` has overload for `char*` which expects *null-terminated* array of characters. Because you create eye matrix, first byte is 1, next one is 0. `1` represents whitespace character, that is why you see nothing on console (try to assign `test_u[0] = 65`, then you will see printed *A* character).
To print address you have to use casting to `void`:

```
cout << "test_u ptr address:" << (void*)test_u <<endl;
```